# Practical / Applied application security

Tags: c#, .net, security, vfs

Alright so here is my issue. I'm working a game engine that will eventually be multilayer. this engine allows games to be written in either a .Net language or Lua (the built in scripting engine). For security however I'd would like to prevent people from viewing these files and of course prevent them from editing them. My solution was to make a Virtual File System with encrypted headers. This way it would be difficult to discover the contents of the game data files, and if somehow someone did, they wouldn't be able to edit them without the key otherwise it would be invalid.

Another issue with the current game is that it connects to a SQL data to get certain data, this means the DB connection string and password is stored inside the application.

However, how do you deal with storing passwords inside a .Net application? I know for a fact that they can be decompiled and it wouldn't make sense to store secret keys inside a readable configuration file so how do most professionals do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically client applications do not directly connect to the database.  Instead the connect to a server which handles the remote calls on behalf of the application.  In such a scenario the only thing that needs the password to the database, is the server.

In modern .Net world the server is usually built using [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)